# applying css style to multiple jquery cached variables without repeating css style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi I have this code in `javascript` for `classic asp` page. There are no css classes so everything is done in `javascript`

```
var $a= $('#a'), $v= $('#v'), $s= $('#s'), $n= $('#n');
```

how can i apply the following css `.css({ 'border-width': '2px' })`to all these variables without repeating the `css` style

i tried this `$([$a, $v, $s]).css({ 'border-width': '2px' });`but it does not work. can any one help please. thanks

Comment: `$('#a, #b , #s, #n').css({ 'border-width': '2px' })` do this way..

Comment: try $("#a, #v, #s, #n).css({ 'border-width': '2px' });

Comment: Why not just use CSS? `#a, #v, #s, #n { border-width: 2px; }`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan. the problem is i have to reuse the cache variable which are used multiple times within the function and code reviewer won't accept this way

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ohh sorry i have edited my comment thanx :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using variables, you can use the elements directly. Multiple elements should be separated by comma.

```
$('#a, #v, #s, #n').css({ 'border-width': '2px' });
```

Answer (score 0):

> With only css :

```
#a, #v, #s, #n { border-width: 2px; }
```

> With js:

```
$('#a, #v, #s, #n').css({ 'border-width': '2px' });
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your cache variable and use it like below for re-usability

```
var cachevar = $('#a, #v, #s, #n');
cachevar.css({ 'border-width': '2px' });
```